# Remote Calls & SMS

Tags: calls

I am sick of using 2 phones. I have a private one and a company phone. Call forwarding from company phone to private is easy done with SIM Settings... but how to make a call from the private phone in order to use the number of the business one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the answer to this but here are a few things you could try.

Are you able to take the sim card out? If so, a service like rightcall might work  although it would need credit adding to the service. I'm not sure if there is a service that will let you do this for free, but I am also interested in this since I have several phones that I use.

There is a sim card called one-sim or something like that. It supposedly allows you to copy 16 sim-cards onto it and then you can use one sim card for 16 numbers.

However, I'm not sure if this actually works or not and you would probably need permission from the service provider and destroy the original sim otherwise it may be classed as sim card cloning.

Here is a link.

www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/33515-39-multi-cards-phone-solution-super

You could also set a service up so that you could text the number you want to dial to the business phone and have the phone ring that number and your number as a conference call. Although, I'm not sure how to do this but an app like MacroDroid, automate or Tasker would probably work. These are automation apps which can be quite difficult to work out how to use but are really powerful with the right set up.

MacroDroid is quite easy to use and tasker is probably the most powerful but harder to use.

If you figure it out let me know :)